# Creating Grid Filter Range with 2 text boxes for serial nbrs

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Getting this error on the code for:
serialTo = $("input.serial-from", filterCell).data("kendoTextBox").value(),

JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference occurred

I've tried different combinations and none seem to work.  I'd assume the "kendoTextBox" would suffice but that is where it is throwing the error.
It seems to work with the 'kendoNumericTexBox' or no errors come up.
But, I don't want it to be a numeric in the long run, as it is a character string not just nbrs.  (example - '00000012' or 'LOT00292').
The code I copied was from a solution for some date ranges from the Telerik site.

'''jquery
    function betweenFilter(args) {
        var filterCell = args.element.parents(".k-filtercell");

```
    filterCell.empty();
    filterCell.html('<span style="display:flex; justify-content:center;"><span>From: </span><input  class="serial-from"/><span> To: </span><input  class="serial-to"/></span>');

    $(".serial-from", filterCell).kendoNumericTextBox({
        change: function (e) {
            var serialFrom = e.sender.value(),
                serialTo = $("input.serial-from", filterCell).data("kendoTextBox").value(),
                dataSource = $("#divParts").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;

            if (serialFrom & serialTo) {
                var filter = { logic: "and", filters: [] };
                filter.filters.push({ field: "SERIAL_NBR", operator: "gte", value: serialFrom });
                filter.filters.push({ field: "SERIAL_NBR", operator: "lte", value: serialTo });
                dataSource.filter(filter);
            }
        }
    });
    $(".serial-to", filterCell).kendoNumericTextBox({
        change: function (e) {
            var serialFrom = $("input.serial-to", filterCell).data("kendoTextBox").value(),
                serialTo = e.sender.value(),
                dataSource = $("#divParts").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;

            if (serialFrom & serialTo) {
                var filter = { logic: "and", filters: [] };
                filter.filters.push({ field: "SERIAL_NBR", operator: "gte", value: serialFrom });
                filter.filters.push({ field: "SERIAL_NBR", operator: "lte", value: serialTo });
                dataSource.filter(filter);
            }
        }
    });

};
```

''''

Just need a second pair of eyes to see what I'm doing wrong or missing within this code.
Users would want to type in a range of serial nbrs to display within the Kendo grid of Parts.  kind of like '000001' to '0000200'.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There is no kendo widget which represents an ordinary textbox, so any attempt to retrieve a widget via `.data("kendoTextBox")` is not going to work. It is possible to style an ordinary input element so that it matches the other controls however, simply add the `k-textbox` class like so:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="k-textbox" />
```

If you would rather use a kendo widget instead, you might find the [MaskedTextBox](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/maskedtextbox/index) a better fit to your use-case than the numeric version (also see [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/maskedtextbox)). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and information.  I tried the k-textbox and that seemed to be the trick.  Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, glad this helped to get you moving again. If you feel this has answered your question sufficiently, please would you mind marking the answer as accepted. If not, and you need further clarification leave another comment or modify your question and I'll see what I can do. Regards.